# Android: Easiest way to change the colour of a png file

Tags: android, graphics, colors, png, drawable

I'm writing a game which has a basic sprite (a balloon) - currently I have 2 different color balloon PNG files which I have created, I need to create more (probably another 5 or so) and don't want to have like 7 different png files. (that would be 20 extra files as I have 4 different sizes for scaling purposes)  I would rather stick to 1 - the ones I have at the moment are yellow and red (almost solid, but not quite - they have details on them).

Question - is there a simple way to alter the colour of my existing PNG files?  I've seen people mention `setColor` and `setColorFilter` but I can't work out how to use these. Also will these even work on PNG files that already have a colour or do they only work on White PNG files (I don't think my PNG's can realistically be just white)?

Thank you all any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to define a custom ColorMatrix with random r g b values:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(256);
int g = rand.nextInt(256);
int b = rand.nextInt(256);

ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
cm.set(new float[] {
                   1, 0, 0, 0, r,
                   0, 1, 0, 0, g,
                   0, 0, 1, 0, b,
                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }); // last line is antialias
paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, toX, toY, paint);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You'd best use this with grayscale input.

Comment: Hey guys thanks very much, I will give the suggestion a try, I can certainly convert my current graphics to grey-scale - cheers!

Comment: Nitin and Peekler - sorry I've been ill so haven't been able to get to my computer sooner.  I've looked over both suggestions and I've implemented Peekler's method because it the simpler of the two and seems to do what I need.  But thank you both very much for your help it is much appreciated.  I need to know how to exlude a certain colour from the change - my balloons have a black border and I'd like to keep this black - any ideas?  Or should I open a new question?  Thanks again all!

Answer (score 11):

You can use just black baloon png file to create different color baloons.

The below code sets the color using some fancy blending mode trickery.

```
protected BitmapDrawable setIconColor(int color) {
    if (color == 0) {
        color = 0xffffffff;
    }

    final Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable maskDrawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_icon_mask);
    if (!(maskDrawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap maskBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) maskDrawable).getBitmap();
    final int width = maskBitmap.getWidth();
    final int height = maskBitmap.getHeight();

    Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    Paint maskedPaint = new Paint();
    maskedPaint.setColor(color);
    maskedPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, maskedPaint);

    BitmapDrawable outDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, outBitmap);
    return outDrawable;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Been at this one over an hour. Was attempting to color markers (Google Map v2 API) based on user setting. You saved me! Much better than having an image (drawable) for each color.